# Can't align text on menu to the right side

Tags: html, css

I've got a website: http://myrkur.net

I'm trying to move the menu so that the links are displayed on the right side of the window. Currently they are on the left side.

I've tried lots of text-align: right;'s but none of them seem to work.

I've managed to get the menu to stick to the top during scrolling, but when that succeeded the menu links went from the center to behind the logo.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="head" class="sticky">
    <div id="bar">
      <div id="menu" class="sticky">
        <div class="link"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="mailto:system@myrkur.net">Contact</a></div>
        <div class="link"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="https://members.myrkur.net/">System</a></div>
        <div class="link"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="http://wiki.myrkur.net">Wiki</a></div>
        <div class="link"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="https://members.myrkur.net/addalbum.php">Add album</a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="logo" class="sticky">
          <a href="http://www.myrkur.net"><img src="oldie/img/myrkur-logo.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[myrkur.net](https://myrkur.net)

And here is the CSS:

```
#head {
 background-color:#5F5F5F;
 height:40px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 9999;
 width: 100%;
}

#menu{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: right;
 width:100%;
 height:25px;
 background-color:#5F5F5F;
 position: sticky;
 position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 padding: 5px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: box;
 -webkit-box-align: right;
 -moz-box-align: right;
 box-align: right;
 -webkit-box-pack: right;
 -moz-box-pack: right;
 box-pack: right;
}

#menu .link a{
 float:right;
 padding:4px;
 display:block;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:10px;
 text-decoration:none;
 -webkit-border-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius:0px;
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size:11px;
 color:#aaaaaa;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}

#menu .link a:hover{
 background-color:#5F5F5F;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
 border-bottom:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 border-color:#5F5F5F;
}


#bar {
 width:100%;
 height: 10px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding:0px;
 padding-top:12px;
 padding-left:75px;
 text-align:right;
 position:sticky;
}

#logo {
 position:absolute;
 top:3px;
 left:65px;
}

#head h1 {
 font-size: 11px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-align: right;
 color: #FAFAFA;
 background-color: #90897a;
 padding:5px 15px;
 margin:0px
}

#head p {
 padding:5px;
 margin:0px;
}
```

[CSS](https://myrkur.net/oldie.css)

Comment: I've added my old menu back on the site, but now I can't seem to move the menu to the top right, instead it hovers in the middle. Also position:sticky is not working for me. Please see http://myrkur.net for real time demo.

Comment: and for more clean design contact me..

Answer (score 1):

> Remove display: box; display: -webkit-box; display: -moz-box; property from #menu.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#head {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 30px 25px 30px
}

#bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo img {
  width: 10%
}

#menu {
  text-align: right;
}

#menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#menu li a {
  color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #bar {
    grid-template-columns: auto !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  
  #menu {
    text-align: center !important;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="head" class="sticky">
    <div id="bar">
      <div id="logo" class="sticky">
        <a href="http://www.myrkur.net"><img src="oldie/img/myrkur-logo.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <ul id="menu" class="sticky">
        <li class="link"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="mailto:system@myrkur.net">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="https://members.myrkur.net/">System</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="http://wiki.myrkur.net">Wiki</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="https://members.myrkur.net/addalbum.php">Add album</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have aligned the image left, if you want to keep it on right then just change the divs